# Nginx SSL_ERROR

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I've managed to set up a Nginx server on an old laptop connected to my router. MY problem is that when accesing it via the `public ip` i get `This site can’t provide a secure connection` and `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` while via the internal ip everything works fine.

I do not have a domain name, in my `nginx` config `server_name` is set to default. I don't really need nor care to use HTTPS but i can't figure out where might the problem be.

My configuration is Django+Gunicorn+Nginx.

I read about Let's Encrypt and Certbot but they only issue SSL certificates for domain names so that doesn't help me.

Bottom line: Is there a setting that i might have overlooked and how can i disable HTTPS?

Comment: Post your nginx config

Answer (score 0):

To disable HTTPS, configure your nginx to only listen and serve requests on port 80